# Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" in Zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, sendmail

i tried to sent email from my system but got this error messages.

```
Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

i already see the others similar post but can't resolve my problem. i tried to change my code from "ssl" to "tls' but get1 the another error. Since i upload my project into University server, so i can't do anything with server configuration. This is my code so far :

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'ssl',
            'auth' => 'login',
            'username' => 'somename@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$email = 'somename1@gmail.com';
$username = 'John';
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml("sdsd");
$mail->setFrom('somename@gmail.com');
$mail->addTo($email, $username);
$mail->setSubject('Profile Activation');
$mail->send($transport);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenSSL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) support isn't enabled on your web server. You can use `phpinfo()` to see what extensions your PHP installation supports. If OpenSSL isn't one of them you're out of luck using SSL or TLS.

Comment: Is it in row "Registered Stream Socket Transports", if yes your right. Because only tcp and udp were stated. Is there any others way to send mail???

Comment: No, it's has it own title named openssl. If you can't find it it's not enabled.

Comment: here.. "OpenSSL support : disabled (install ext/openssl)". this is what i found.

Comment: If it's disabled you can't use SSL or TLS on which GMail's SMTP server depends on. You will have to find another SMTP server that doesn't use secure encryption or talk to your university staff to enable openssl.

Comment: is there any suggestion on other another SMTP server??

Comment: I recommend you accept an answer and ask it as another question.

Answer (score 3):

as suggested openSSL is Not enable in your php..

```
Open php.ini
uncomment the following:
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

then restart the server..

Hope this helps, also you can use this http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: i cant do anything to configure php.ini because the server is only can access by web master only..i mean, the university staff.

Comment: well then you can ask them to do that, there is no harm in that.. !