# PHP OpenSSL undefined constant OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1

Tags: php, windows, php-openssl

I am running PHP 5.2.13 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine (Windows 7 equivalent).

I'm mostly writing this just because I get a [google dead end](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22Use%20of%20undefined%20constant%20OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1%22) on searching for the warning and I'm trying to add something for it.

I am getting the following notice / warning:

> Use of undefined constant OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1 - assumed 'OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1'
>
> openssl_verify() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given

When running this line of code:

`return openssl_verify($data, $signature, $this->getPublicKey(), OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1);`

Obviously the second warning is caused by the first.

However the problem isn't that the OpenSSL library isn't loaded, as I have the following output from `phpinfo`:

```
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

This is working on all other machines that it has been tested on, so there is something machine specific.

The only difference I have spotted is the following from phpinfo:

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp
```

vs on machines where it is working:

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
```

But I'm not sure if that's a red herring or not.

Comment: How you get the **public key** for openssl_verfiy() ?

Comment: i am sure you already visit this but still take look with different type and try to debug:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php

Comment: @SoniVimal that's via a `fread` of the DSA public key that I'm using. So I'm passing in a string of the file contents. But that doesn't have much to do with the fact that the open_ssl library doesn't recognise the constant `OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1` which is part of the library

Comment: PHP 5.2.x is long dead and you really shouldn't be using it for anything security-related

Comment: @GordonM Yes indeed. I'm pushing for an upgrade, but for now it remains at 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for the problem was to uninstall PHP completely and run the `php-5.2.13-nts-x86.msi` installer and install the OpenSSL library through there.

I had done a manual installation of the OpenSSL library rather than using the Windows installer.

I now do have the following in `phpinfo`:

```
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.zlib, https, ftps
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
```

As far as I can tell even according to the [openssl installation documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) there shouldn't be a requirement to have to install using the installer. On other machines I haven't had this problem. Altering the 'Registered Stream Socket Transports' to include ssl should only require installing the open_ssl library and adding a line to the `php.ini` file e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500266/327074).

Comment: If you're reinstalling PHP anyway, why not install a newer version?  PHP 5.2 has gone unmaintained for years and can't be trusted for anything that requires security

Comment: @GordonM Damn fine point. However the software we're using is fully tested on PHP 5.2, switching versions requires a full retest of the system.